# How to make a task more independent?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Originally I wrote my C# program using Threads and ThreadPooling, but most of the users on here were telling me Async was a better approach for more efficiency. My program sends JSON objects to a server until status code of 200 is returned and then moves on to the next task.

The problem is once one of my Tasks retrieves a status code of 200, it waits for the other Tasks to get 200 code and then move onto the next Task. I want each task to continue it's next task without waiting for other Tasks to finish (or catch up) by receiving a 200 response.

Below is my main class to run my tasks in parallel.

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.Add (getItemAsync (i));
        }

        Task.WhenAny (tasks);
    }
```

Here is the getItemAsync() method that does the actual sending of information to another server. Before this method works, it needs a key. The problem also lies here, let's say I run 100 tasks, all 100 tasks will wait until every single one has a key.

```
    public static async Task getItemAsync (int i)
    {
        if (key == "") {
            await getProductKey (i).ConfigureAwait(false);
        } 

        Uri url = new Uri ("http://www.website.com/");

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent (new[] {
            ...
        });

        while (!success) {
            using (HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync (url, content)) {
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    Console.WriteLine(resultContent);

                    success=true;
                }   
            }
        }

        await doMoreAsync (i);

    }
```

Here's the function that retrieves the keys, it uses HttpClient and gets parsed.

```
    public static async Task getProductKey (int i)
    {
        string url = "http://www.website.com/key";

        var stream = await client.GetStringAsync (url).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var doc = new HtmlDocument ();
        doc.LoadHtml (stream);

        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes ("//input[@name='key']") [0];

        try {
            key = node.Attributes ["value"].Value;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
```

After every task receives a key and has a 200 status code, it runs doMoreAsync(). I want any individual Task that retrieved the 200 code to run doMoreAsync() without waiting for other tasks to catch up. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Main method is not waiting for a Task to complete, it justs fires off a bunch of async tasks and returns.
If you want to await an async task you can only do that from an async method. Workaround is to kick off an async task from the Main method and wait for its completion using the blocking `Task.Wait()`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.Add (getItemAsync (i));
        }

        var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks); // This awaits one task
    }).Wait();
}
```

When you are invoking `getItemAsync()` from an async method, you can remove the `ConfigureAwait(false)` as well. `ConfigureAwait(false)` just makes sure some code does not execute on the UI thread.

If you want to append another task to a task, you can also append it to the previous Task directly by using `ContinueWith()`:

```
getItemAsync(i).ContinueWith(anotherTask);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually discovered ContinueWith a few minutes ago and I'm testing that method now. It keeps returning the same thread #. And var finishedTask = await tasks.WhenAny() doesn't work. It says "System.Collections.Generic.list" does not contain a definition "whenany".

Comment: I meant `await Task.WhenAny(tasks);` This will wait for one task in the list to be finished. You could then go and remove that task from that list since it is completed.
Also tasks are not mapped to threads 1:1. A bunch of tasks can be executed within the same thread. A task can execute while another is stuck awaiting something.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working in my main. It's throwing me that system.collections.generic.list error.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be that you're sharing the `key` field across all your concurrently-running asynchronous operations. This will inevitably lead to race hazards. Instead, you should alter your `getProductKey` method to *return* each retrieved key as the result of its asynchronous operation:

```
                        // ↓ result type of asynchronous operation
public static async Task<string> getProductKey(int i)
{
    // retrieval logic here

    // return key as result of asynchronous operation
    return node.Attributes["value"].Value;
}
```

Then, you consume it like so:

```
public static async Task getItemAsync(int i)
{
    string key;
    try 
    {
        key = await getProductKey(i).ConfigureAwait(false);
    } 
    catch 
    {
        // handle exceptions
    }

    // use local variable 'key' in further asynchronous operations
}
```

Finally, in your main logic, use a `WaitAll` to prevent the console application from terminating before all your tasks complete. Although `WaitAll` is a blocking call, it is acceptable in this case since you want the main thread to block.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tasks.Add(getItemAsync(i));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried the WaitAll() method but it keeps giving me this wierd error saying, "argument #1 cannot convert 'system.collections.generic.list<system.threading.tasks.task>' expression to type 'system.threading.task.tasks[]"

Comment: @CO: I was missing a `.ToArray()` call on the `tasks` list. Try the updated version.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out alittle while ago. It's still not working independently but the program doesn't close out quickly anymore. It's still waiting for all the Tasks to retrieve there keys to continue to the next step.

Comment: I'm going to try and approach this with ContinueWith() it's alittle tricky for some reason. Seemed straight forward in the documents.